# Azure DevOps - Batching using multi-repo trigger

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've tried multi repo trigger using azure devops.

```
resources:   repositories:
    - repository: ToolsRepo
      name: ToolsRepo
      type: git  
      trigger:
        batch: true
        branches:
          include:
          - master
```

trigger does not work. It works only if I remove batch: true line. How could I make it work together with batching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the test result, if you set `batch: true` to other repos (not the repo where the current yaml pipeline file is located), then CI trigger from other repos will not trigger the pipeline.

[image]

The CI trigger from the current repo can trigger the pipeline normally.

[image]

So I am afraid that `batch: true` is currently not supported in multi-repo trigger. In addition, the `batch` argument is not specified in the multi-repo trigger [yaml syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers).

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: yep, you are right - it is not supported, yet. I contacted MS and they replied:
Thank you for your feedback.
In the new feature Repository resource, we do not support the batching in the repository CI. And we recommend you can create a suggestion ticket, so our product team will know this good suggestion.
Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: This really needs to be fixed, especially where terraform is used with a locking state file. trying to access the file will cause the pipeline to fail of it's already in use, hence changes need to be batched.